# How does one correct the question on which a bounty was placed?

Tags: support, bounties

Okay, I love this question: [What translation of Augustine's Confessions is the easiest to read in English?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/19177/what-translation-of-augustines-confessions-is-the-easist-to-read) and awarded a bounty on it.

Or, at least I was like 99% positive I was on that question.

For some reason I cannot explain, the bounty appears on this one [Is there a good example of believers seeking out advice from other believers in the Bible, especially one that is a story children would understand?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/19222/is-there-a-good-example-of-believers-seeking-out-advice-from-other-believers-in) however.

Is there any mechanism for correcting this?  And, is there any way this couldn't be attributed to user error?

Comment: Sounds like divine intervention to me.  Flag a mod, link this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flag the question with the bounty and explain the situation to the moderators in a custom flag reason.  They *might* choose to end the bounty and refund your reputation if they believe it was an honest mistake.

Note that you should do this right away; the longer the bounty has been active the less likely a mod is to cancel it, since you're "paying" for the attention it gets.

Comment: What about the possibility that it was not a user error (the final sentence in the question)? Could it be a bug?

Comment: @Wikis If this is something that is observed a number of times, or can be reproduced, perhaps.  Unless there's reason to believe otherwise, it's more likely that the user simply had the wrong tab open.